# JetBrains Toolbox app is blank on Windows

Tags: jetbrains-toolbox

I installed JetBrains Toolbox app on my Windows 10. But when I start it up, it just shows a blank border, like this:

[image]

I tried to reinstall it but still not work. Someone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks similar to [ALL-1419](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/ALL-1419). Please try applying a workaround from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/ALL-1419#comment=27-2027477 (set `JETBRAINS_TOOLBOX_NO_SOFTWARE_OPEN_GL=true`)