# JetBrains Toolbox won't open

Tags: jetbrains-toolbox

I use JetBrains Toolbox at work to manage my different projects and it has stopped working for a few days.

When I click on the icon, no windows open. Note that this is not the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46029501/5018771), I just have nothing apparent happening at all.

---

What I've already tried:

- Restarting the computer
- Redownloading the toolbox from the [official website](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/) and reinstalling

---

Additional info:

- I'm on Windows 10
- Options "Open" and "Settings" seem to do nothing.
- Option "Check for Updates" says I'm up-to-date
- Options "Show Log File in Explorer", "Send Feedback" and Version work as expected

Here is an excerpt from my `log.txt` (This may contain relevant info). **Some file seems not to be found, could this be the source of the problem?**

```
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.063 INFO  Processes            54     Executing "C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/Toolbox/self/1.11.4231.remove-1535700212822/cef/jetbrains-toolbox-cef.exe" args "--toolbox-server-ws=ws://127.0.0.1:54087|--toolbox-server-token=31e0266c59954df38d2313109d121391|--toolbox-data=C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\JetBrains\\Toolbox\\cef-data|--toolbox-cache=C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\JetBrains\\Toolbox\\cef-cache|--toolbox-log=C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\JetBrains\\Toolbox\\logs|--toolbox-server-pid=3768|--minimize"
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.064 INFO  DPI                  16     DefaultLocation: Screen  point:  QPoint(2315,371)
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.064 INFO  CEFProcess           106    CEF process completed! 
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.065 INFO  DPI                  19     DefaultLocation: Screen  devicePixelRatio:  1
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.065 INFO  DPI                  22     DefaultLocation: Screen  remote desktop:  false
/myusername/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/Toolbox/self/1.11.4231.remove-1535700212822/cef/jetbrains-toolbox-cef.exe"
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.066 INFO  CEFProcess           103    Running CEF process from  "C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/Toolbox/self/1.11.4231.remove-1535700212822/cef/jetbrains-toolbox-cef.exe" workdir= "C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/Toolbox/self/1.11.4231.remove-1535700212822"
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.066 INFO  DPI                  29     DefaultLocation: Screen 1:       physical size       QSizeF(600, 340)
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.067 INFO  DPI                  30     DefaultLocation: Screen 1:       logical size        QSize(1920, 1080)
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.068 INFO  DPI                  31     DefaultLocation: Screen 1:       available geometry  QRect(0,0 1920x1040)
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.069 INFO  DPI                  32     DefaultLocation: Screen 1:                 geometry  QRect(0,0 1920x1080)
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.069 INFO  DPI                  33     DefaultLocation: Screen 1:                 size      QSize(1920, 1040)
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.070 INFO  DPI                  34     DefaultLocation: Screen 1:       devicePixelRatio    1
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.071 INFO  DPI                  35     DefaultLocation: Screen 1:       logicalDotsPerInch  96 96 96
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.072 INFO  DPI                  36     DefaultLocation: Screen 1:       physicalDotsPerInch 80.9812 81.28 80.6824
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.073 INFO  CEFResources         33     Resources size:  "787035"
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.073 INFO  DPI                  37     DefaultLocation: Screen 1:       depth               32
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.073 INFO  Processes            54     Executing "C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/Toolbox/self/1.11.4231.remove-1535700212822/cef/jetbrains-toolbox-cef.exe" args "--toolbox-server-ws=ws://127.0.0.1:54087|--toolbox-server-token=31e0266c59954df38d2313109d121391|--toolbox-data=C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\JetBrains\\Toolbox\\cef-data|--toolbox-cache=C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\JetBrains\\Toolbox\\cef-cache|--toolbox-log=C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\JetBrains\\Toolbox\\logs|--toolbox-server-pid=3768|--minimize"
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.074 INFO  DPI                  38     DefaultLocation: Screen 1:       primaryOrientation  Qt::ScreenOrientation(LandscapeOrientation)
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.075 INFO  CEFProcess           106    CEF process completed! 
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.075 INFO  DPI                  39     DefaultLocation: Screen 1:       orientation         Qt::ScreenOrientation(LandscapeOrientation)
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.075 INFO  CEFProcess           108    CEF process failed:  "File is not found: C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/Toolbox/self/1.11.4231.remove-1535700212822/cef/jetbrains-toolbox-cef.exe"
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.075 INFO  DPI                  40     DefaultLocation: Screen 1:       nativeOrientation   Qt::ScreenOrientation(PrimaryOrientation)
1.11.4231 3768 2018-09-03T17:33:00.076 WARN  CEFProcess           92     CEF Process last started 10 msecs ago. Waiting 4990 msecs for the restart attempt # 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this was a bug in version `1.11.4231` of the JetBrains Toolbox.

The bug has already been documented on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/ALL-2971) and solved in version `1.11.4269` of the Toolbox. A simple update solves the issue.

Comment: I will download 1.24.12080 now and have some bug

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `{ "graphics_api": "Software" }` to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\.settings.json`.
2. Add environment variable `JETBRAINS_TOOLBOX_NO_SOFTWARE_OPEN_GL=true`.

[image]